# Proving, for holomorphic function $f,g$ on $U\setminus\{0\}$ have same derivative on $U\setminus\{0\}$, then $f$ and $g$ differ by a constant

Tags: complex-analysis

First let me describe in more detail.

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open disc with center $0$.

Suppose that both $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic functions on $U \setminus \{0 \}$.

If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}$ on $U \setminus \{ 0 \}$, then i want to show that $f$ and $g$ differ by a constant.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered $f-g$? Its derivative is $0$ everywhere: what can you conclude?

Comment: This is the same as showing that if $\dfrac{df}{dz}=0$ everywhere in the punctured disk then $f$ is constant in the punctured disk. That's a simpler way of saying it. $\qquad$

Comment: Notice this difference: $$ U\setminus\{0\} \text{ versus } U \backslash\{0\} $$ The former provides the amount of space to the left and right of the binary operation symbol that is standard for binary operation symbols; the latter does not. The former is standard for this occasion. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Crostul said, we can just consider the function $h$ with $h'=0$ on $U\setminus\{0\}$ and prove that $h=k$ where $k$ is some constant.

First, $U\setminus\{0\}$ is obviously a connected set.

Let $A$ be the subset such that $h=k$ where $k$ is any value $h$ takes.

If $h(x_n)=k$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(x_n)=k$ when $\lim{x_n}=x\in A$

Thus, $A$ is closed.

Now, consider an $x\in A$.

Take a disk around $x$ such that this disk is still in $U\setminus\{0\}$.

Let $y$ be any element of this disk and then take a straight line between $x$ and $y$ (this is possible since the disk is convex.)

Write $f(t)=h(tx+(1-t)y)$ thus turning this into a one-variable problem and then, using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule:

$f'(t)=0$ on the interval $[0;1]$.

Thus, $f$ is constant, and $h(y)=h(x)=k$.

Thus $A$ is open.

Therefore, we conclude $A=U\setminus\{0\}$ since $A\neq\emptyset$.

We are done.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I appreciate it (and I just learned the appropriate way to write a set-minus).